# Study the relationship between two topologies

Tags: general-topology

Someone could help me solve the following statement:

> Let $T'$ be the topology generated by $B = \{(a,b): a,b ∈ \Bbb R -\Bbb  Q, a<b\}$,
>   study the relationship between the topologies $T'$ and the usual
>   topology $Tu$ in $\Bbb R$.

Can someone tell me if the next resolution is correct?

Since (a, b) ∈ Tu : a, b ∈ R-Q you have that T' ⊂ Tu and as (c, d) ∉ T': (c, d) ∈ R you have to Tu ≠ T '

Comment: You compare two topologies the easiest by taking a base element from one topology, and checking whether it's open in the other. If you can do that both ways, then the topologies are equal. If you can only do it one way, then one topology is coarser than the other, and if it's impossible both ways, then they are incomparable. Have a go, and tell us the results.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: For example, any of the elements of the base of Tu are real numbers, that is, that the element (a, b) : a, b ∈ℚ. And this element of the base (a, b) ∉ T' by the fact that a, b ∉ ℝ−ℚ.

On the contrary, (c, d) are elements of the base T' such that c, d ∈ R - Q and (c, d) also belongs to the base of the usual topology. For what  Tu contains T '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you define the usual topology by means of open balls: $U\subseteq \Bbb R$ is open iff for each $x_0\in U$, there exists $r>0$ such that  $B_r(x_0):=\{\,x\in\Bbb R:|x-x_0<r\,\}\subseteq U$.

Each $(a,b)\in B$ is $T_u$-open because it is the open ball of radius $r:=\frac{b-a}2>0$ around $\frac{a+b}2$. Then also every $T'$-open set is $T_u$-open.

On the other hand, let $U$ be $T_u$-open. Given $x_0\in U$, there exists $r>0$ with $B_r(x_0)\subseteq U$. the non-empty open interval $(x_0-r,x_0)$  is not a subset of $\Bbb Q$, hence there exists $a\in\Bbb R-\Bbb Q$ with $x_0-r<a<x_0$. Similarly, we find $b\in\Bbb R-\Bbb Q$ with $x_0<a<x_0+r$. Then $(a,b)\in B$ and $x_0\in (a,b)\subseteq U$. We concldue that $U$ is the union of elements of $B$, hence is $T'$-open.

In summary, $T'=T_u$.

Comment: Since (a, b) ∈ Tu : a, b ∈ R-Q you have that T' ⊂ Tu and as (c, d) ∉ T': (c, d) ∈ R you have to Tu ≠ T '

Answer (score 1):

As all members of $B$ are open intervals, and so members of $\mathcal{T}_u$, $\mathcal{T}' \subseteq \mathcal{T}_u$.

On the other hand, if $(a,b)$ is any real open interval, find a sequence of irrationals $a_n$ such that $a_n \in (a,b)$ for all $n$ and $a_n \to a$.
Likewise find $b_n \in (a,b)$, all irrational, such that $b_n \to b$. Then

$$(a,b) = \bigcup_n (a_n, b_n)$$ and so $(a,b) \in \mathcal{T}'$. So $\mathcal{T}_u \subseteq \mathcal{T}'$, showing the topologies to be the same.